# Number of connected components of a preimage

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  be a (smooth) function and $a$ a regular value of $f$. Is there a (easy) way to determine the number of connected components of the submanifold $f^{-1}(a)$ ? One can assume extra regularity restrictions if necessary.

I am thinking about integration, cohomology or stuff like that. Any lead would be appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: This is already moderately tricky in the case $n = 1$ and $f$ a polynomial, where you're looking to compute the number of real roots. What kind of an answer would be useful for you?

Comment: By lack of compacity, in general no. Take for example a Morse function. Then you can imaginate about anything for the number of connected components.